# multiple conditions on multiple variables

Tags: sas

would really love to get some help on a sas program i am trying to write

I have five variables that have the options Interest or Rewards
call them wo1 wo2 wo3 wo4 wo5

is there a way to do an if statement that checks all five for the value of "Interest" and then produces a calcualted variable with the totals of the variable that holds the amount value which are wo1amt wo2amt wo3mt etc.

and the ones that do not have the value of interest return a value of 0.

or would i need to do an if statement for each, creating a calc var for each and then summing them all together with another ??

any assistance, direction would be very appreciated...

Comment: Please provide sample data, sample result and show us what you already tried.

Comment: Your question nicely highlights the problems with having data in a 'wide' format. You should ideally restructure your data to have just 'wo' and 'woamt' variables, and a new third variable called 'index' or similar. Each current observation would become five observations in the transposed, tall, narrow data set. Then you can do what you want with a single IF statement. With the data as you have, the next best option would be to declare arrays mapping to the two sets of five variables, and then loop over the arrays.

Comment: thanks for the tip! i will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, it looks like you will need multiple if statements.

You could initialize a total variable, and then add to it for each contributing variable, like this:

```
total = 0;
if wo1 = 'Interest' then total = total + wo1amt;
if wo2 = 'Interest' then total = total + wo2amt;
if wo3 = 'Interest' then total = total + wo3amt;
if wo4 = 'Interest' then total = total + wo4amt;
if wo5 = 'Interest' then total = total + wo5amt;
```

Comment: Thanks Don - this makes sense and seems like the easiest option should not be able to work out the previous sugg.

Comment: once again, thank you for your help. this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays work nicely for situations like this.

```
array wo(*) wo1-wo5;
array woamt(*) wo1amt wo2amt wo3amt wo4amt wo5amt;
total = 0;
do i = 1 to 5;
   total + woamt(i)*(wo(i)='Interest');
end;
```